# python list += str

Tags: python

Есть переменная типа list и  переменная типа str

```
lst = [1, 2]
string = 'ab'
lst = lst + string # TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
lst += string # [1, 2, 'a', 'b']
```

Почему += позволяет это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В любой изменяемой последовательности (в том числе `list`) оператор `+=` эквивалентен вызову метода `extend` (см. таблицу ["Mutable Sequence Types"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) в документации по Python):

```py
>>> lst = [1, 2]
>>> lst += [3, 4]
>>> lst.extend([5, 6])
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

А метод `extend` списка принимает итерируемый объект (каким и является `str`) и добавляет к концу списка каждый элемент переданного ему итерируемого объекта. Элементами строки (`str`) являются отдельные её символы:

```py
>>> for c in 'abc':
...     print(c)
... 
a
b
c
```

В тоже время оператор `+` принимает *только* список, так как не очень понятно, что должно получится при сложении списка и строки - список или строка?

Answer (score 3):

`+=` и `+` это разные операторы, которые вызывают разные специальные (магические) методы.
Для `+=` это `__iadd__`. Он используется, когда мы хотим изменить существующий объект, если он изменяемый.
Для `+` это `__add__`. В этом случае, как правило, создается новый объект.

`list` реализован на c, но принцип тот же. Вот в данном случае логика класса `list` написана так, чтобы он интерпретировал `+=` как добавление в список. Разработчики языка подумали о нашем удобстве.

Answer (score 2):

Для сложения необходимо строку преобразовать в список:

```py
>>> lst = [1, 2]
>>> string = 'ab'
>>> lst = lst + list(string)  # Преобразовать в список вида ['a', 'b']
[1, 2, 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: Но lst += string позволяет сложить без преобразования строки в список. И хотелось бы узнать почему это возможно