# Почему s = s + ... не работает там, где работает s += ...?

Tags: python, синтаксис

Подскажите, почему выдает ошибку, если написать `s = s + .....`, а если написать `s += .....`, то все верно, ведь `s +=` это тоже самое, что и `s = s + ....`

Вот код (рабочий):

```
step = 5
text = "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"
a = 'привет'
s = []
    
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] in text:
        s += text[(text.index(a[i]) + step) % 32]
        

print(''.join(s))
```

а вот, тоже самое, только s = s + ... :

```
step = 5
text = "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"
a = 'привет'
s = []
    
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] in text:
        s = s + text[(text.index(a[i]) + step) % 32]
        
print(''.join(s))
```

Comment: Если кратко — потому что это на самом деле не то же самое

Comment: За что минус-то?

Comment: @wchistow я не минусовал, но как минимум здесь абсолютно невнятный заголовок, например

Comment: @andreymal, так лучше?

Comment: @wchistow наверное

Comment: @andreymal, хотя-бы по теме. А прошлый заголовок был совсем не по теме - ведь дело здесь не в синтаксисе. 

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [python list += str](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1530920/python-list-str)

Answer (score 5):

Ошибка возникает из-за разницы в типе данных.

В первом случае, когда вы используете оператор "+=", вы добавляете в переменную "s" отдельные символы из строки "text". И таким образом переменная "s" остается типом "list" (список), что позволяет вам в конечном итоге объединить все символы в строку, используя "join".

Во втором случае, когда вы используете оператор "+", вы добавляете символ из строки "text" в переменную "s" напрямую. Но переменная "s" была инициализирована как пустой список, поэтому оператор "+" ожидает объект типа "list", а не символ. Именно поэтому возникает ошибка.

Если вы хотите использовать оператор "+", вам нужно инициализировать переменную "s" как пустую строку, а не список

Answer (score 5):

Оператор `+=` у списка добавляет в конец списка по очереди элементы из итерируемого объекта, а у вас там строка, которая является итерируемым объектом:

```py
>>> for l in 'abc':
...     print(l)
...
a
b
c
```

А оператор `+` объединяет два списка:

```py
>>> [1, 2] + [3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

При этом умеет работать только со списками:

```py
>>> [1, 2] + (3, 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
```

Потому что не понятно, что должно получится в результате сложения, например, списка и кортежа - список или кортеж?

Comment: Ого, так быстро.

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard, чтобы зарабатывать репутацию на SO, нужно быстро печатать. 

Comment: Правило с enSO: ***No rush!***

Answer (score 2):

Дополню другие ответы, может так понятнее будет. По сути для списков

```
s += x
```

Работает так же, как

```
s.extend(x)
```

Метод списка `extend` может принимать на вход строки и символы (отдельный символ - это тоже строка) и добавлять их в конец списка, итерируясь по ним. А вот при сложении

```
s = s + x
```

Уже действуют другие правила, списки можно складывать только со списками.

И это, кстати, логично, что `+=` был реализован как `extend`. И оператор `iadd` (inplace add) и оператор `extend` изменяют исходный список "по месту". А вот обычный оператор сложения `add` создаёт на выходе новый список. Они работают по-разному.

Comment: @andreymal Да, что-то я не проверил, всё надо проверять